# WPF change another application textbox

Tags: wpf, reflection, snoop

I am looking at some application with snoop.

I can see the text of some textbox, I also can edit it.

Now I want to do the same thing but programmatically.
I want to write some text in this textbox programmatically. (Text box from  another application)

I think this is possible because snoop can do it (May be using reflection in some way)

What is the  best way to do this? 
Thank you,